# text file viewer

Tags: debugging, text-files, viewer, apache-chainsaw

I'm looking for a tool to debug file text.
there are many file text format that contain data.

Such as `2734958723fdshkfsdhfkjhewkf3242342`
Which could be data

Number1 `2734`
Number2 `958723`
Text `fdshkfsdhfkjhewkf`
Number 3 `3242342`

I'm looking for a tool that can be difend to parse the file, by definition, and show it parse to easy read. and not look for columns in the text file.

Do you know of any open source project that does that?

update: is it possible to make chainsaw configurable to read other formats?

Answer (score 0):

Chainsaw does not support 'fixed length' parsing of fields, like you are looking for here (field1 is 4 bytes long, field2 is 6, etc).

Chainsaw's file parsing support was designed around the assumption that delimiters would be included in the log file format.